# Updating SQL using PHP - Error

Tags: php, mysql

Right so i have php code to update a SQL table. If i replace $_GET['emailID'] with a number say 1 the database IS updated. But otherwise no update. What seems to be wrong here

Table: emails

Fields: mailbox, emailID

```
$query = 'UPDATE `emails` SET `mailbox`=\'trash\' WHERE `emailID`='.(int)$_GET['emailID'];
```

Comment: Do you get any errors from mysql? Can you print $query before you execute it?

Comment: May be the datatype in the table is int please check once

Comment: @Veerendra yes the data type is int in the table. But the transformation (int) is giving out as 0 if i print $query

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
$query = "UPDATE `emails` SET `mailbox`='trash' WHERE `emailID`=".intval($_GET['emailID']);
```

Comment: I am not sure. Doesn't (int) $var convert $var to int? http://php.net/language.types.type-juggling#language.types.typecasting

Comment: @user4035, Yeah it does. `echo (int)$str='23test';` gives you 23.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran So, his code must give the same result as yours. Frankly, I don't see any errors in this query except for missing parameter escaping. Maybe, the error is somewhere else?

Comment: @user4035, Right. @Haroon, What does this query give you on SQL , `UPDATE emails SET mailbox='trash' WHERE emailID=1` ?

Comment: So my code now is 
$query = "UPDATE `emails` SET `mailbox`=\'trash\' WHERE `emailID`=".intval($_GET['emailID']);
  print $query;
  print "<b>".$_GET['emailID']."</b>";

Output:
UPDATE `emails` SET `mailbox`='trash' WHERE `emailID`=0'1'

Comment: so its giving the output of intval($_GET['emailID']=0 while if i print the variable it is 1.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this,

```
 $query = 'UPDATE `emails` SET `mailbox`=\'trash\' WHERE `emailID`="'.(int)$_GET['emailID'].'" ';
```

Comment: print $query; print $_GET['emailID']; gives me ==>

UPDATE `emails` SET `mailbox`='inbox' WHERE `emailID`="0"'2'

Comment: What is your Email id value ?

Comment: Can you post your complete url with query string?

Answer (score 0):

Value of attribut must be selected by single quotes. Try this:

```
$query = "UPDATE `emails` SET `mailbox` = 'trash' WHERE `emailID` = '" . intval($_GET['emailID']) . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "UPDATE `emails` SET `mailbox`='trash' WHERE `emailID`= ".$_GET['emailID'];
```

Try this one sure it will work